# If all Java Strings are UTF-16 strings then how can char datatype have max size of 2?

Tags: java, character-encoding, char, utf-16, utf

If Strings in Java are UTF-16 then UTF-16 character may have size of 4 bytes.
So 1 UTF-16 character will have to map to 2 chars.

and this would mean that String length may be less than equivalent char[] length.

But that is not the case.

```
Character x = new Character((char) 7000);
String s = new String(""+x+x+x);

byte [] ar =  s.getBytes();
char [] arr =  s.toCharArray();
```

byte array has length 9. 
char array has length 3. 
so how can char have size of 2 bytes ?

So I think char in java may be larger than 2 bytes depending on the need is that correct .

If so what is the max size of char in java ? Or it is variable length and may go upto infinity in future ?

Comment: What are you even talking about with regards to 4 bytes?  The whole point of the UTF-16 encoding is that code points are encoded with 1 or 2 16-bit code units.  16 bits is 2 bytes.  That's the _meaning_ of the 16 in UTF-16.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `String.getBytes()` call doesn't return the UTF-16 internal representation. It returns the string in the platform's default encoding. In your case, that is quite likely to be UTF-8 (though, being a platform-determined thing, you'd need to check to be sure). The UTF-8 encoded form of `(char)7000` (Unicode codepoint `U+1B58 BALINESE DIGIT EIGHT`) is 3 bytes - `E1 AD 98`.  Hence your 9 bytes for 3 chars.

Comment: Okay Even then UTF-16 character may be of 4 bytes then how does that fit in Java Character which is of 2 bytes ?

Comment: It does not fit. Multiple chars are used to represent these codepoints. Look at the codepoint based methods in `String` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @Piyush: UTF-16 uses one 16bit `char` for codepoints `U+0000` to `U+FFFF`, and uses two 16bit `char`s (known as a "surrogate pair") for higher codepoints. Your example value, `(char)7000`, is codepoint `U+1B58`, which fits in one `char` in UTF-16, but is three bytes in UTF-8.